# resize image size then store it in database flask

Tags: python, image, flask, python-imaging-library, reduce

I am using this way to pic image and store it in my database using flask :

```
class Gallery(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Gallery'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,  primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False) 
    rendered_data = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)


def render_picture(data):
    render_pic = base64.b64encode(data).decode('ascii') 
    return render_pic


@app.route('/gallery/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_gallery():
   title = request.form['title']
   file = request.files['file']
   data = file.read()
   render_file = render_picture(data)

   newFile = Gallery(name=file.filename, data=data, rendered_data=render_file, title=title)
   db.session.add(newFile)
   db.session.commit()
   db.session.close()
```

and it is working fine but I need to reduce image size before I store it in my database
I tried Pillow in many ways but it did not work with my way to store the image

can anyone help me reduce image size?

Comment: It's unclear, to me at least, 1) what is in `file`, 2) where the code is for `render_picture()` and 3) what `Gallery()` does. Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my code , the file is image

Comment: It is still unclear what is really in your file. Please show the first 20-30 bytes of your file in hex - if you don't have the ability to dump in hex, you can use https://hexed.it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example, the uploaded image is scaled and stored in the database as binary data. To display it, there is either the possibility of creating a data url of the data or of downloading the data of the image as a file.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import redirect, render_template, request, url_for, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from PIL import Image
import base64
import io

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Gallery(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    img_data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(),
        nullable=True, unique=False, index=False)

    @property
    def b64encoded(self):
        return base64.b64encode(self.img_data).decode()

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    galleries = Gallery.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

def image_resize(file, size=84):
    img = Image.open(file)
    img_size = img.size
    img_ratio = size/img_size[0]
    img.thumbnail((img_size[0]*img_ratio, img_size[1]*img_ratio), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return image_to_bytes(img)

def image_to_bytes(image):
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(stream, format='PNG')
    return stream.getvalue()

@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    if not 'img' in request.files:
        abort(400)

    file = request.files['img']

    gallery = Gallery()
    gallery.img_data = image_resize(file)
    db.session.add(gallery)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/<int:gallery_id>/image')
def download_image(gallery_id):
    gallery = Gallery.query.get_or_404(gallery_id)
    if not gallery.img_data:
        abort(404)

    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(gallery.img_data),
        as_attachment=False,
        mimetype='image/png'
    )
```

Comment: thanks it works like this, and  I don't need to store it as binary data I can use my function ( render_file = render_picture(img_data) ) and it will be the same but resized and I can show it on the same way. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what's in your file and how are you executing it but as long as it works, it's fine. Coming on to your question about resizing image, you are right to use PIL (Python Imaging Library). I am not familiar with base64 and io and I don't think you need them *at all*. The way I resize my images is:

You can create a function to do this as:

```
def save_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
```

I use Python secrets that can be imported as

```
 import secrets
```

that can be used to generate a random name for image so we don't have many images with same name, I  have specified it to be 8 bits as shown above. `form_picture` is an argument here:

```
_,f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/profile_pics', 
picture_fn)  
output_size = (125, 125)
i = Image.open(form_picture)
```

This will define the path of picture, joining `"static/profile_pics"` with `picture_fn` variable that is name of variable defining the actual name of picture. `output_size` function is specifying picture to be of 125 pixels.

```
i.thumbnail(output_size)
i.save(picture_path)
return picture_fn
```

and at end to save above picture.